# Run a script in Linux straight from CD drive (CD was burned in Windows)

Tags: windows, linux, permissions, compact-disc

I have a self-extracting Bash installation script.  I'd like to burn this to CD on my Windows box, drop that in a Linux box, and run the script straight off the CD drive.

Is there a way to add "+x" Permission on the Windows box when creating the CD?

I've been using the built in "writable folder"/"burn to disc" method, but think I have nero sitting around somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the rock ridge extensions. But even so a CD is often mounted noexec, so that +x flag won't help you anyway. You can always run a script directly  by invoking the shell,`sh myscript.sh` to get around that.

Comment: Or, since it's a bash script, `bash myscript.sh`.

Comment: I ended up requiring the end user to call "bash script.sh", as I can't confirm that the disc will be mounted without noexec.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your best bet would be [Cygwin](http://Cygwin) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) to create the permissions for real.

Comment: How would the execute bit be stored on CDFS?

Answer (score 0):

You need burning software that can handle [Rock Ridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge) such as [CDEveryWhere](http://www.i2rd.com/CDEveryWhere/index.shtml), [GEAR PRO](http://www.gearcdr.com/), or possibly mkisofs under Cygwin.